# Oracle - Update column only if source is not null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an update statement that is dynamically being generated within a package.

I need to update the `target_field2` only when `source_field2` is `NOT NULL`, if `NULL` then keep `target_field2` as is.

Hoping there is an easy answer to this. This is the dynamic section in concern:

```
                 ELSIF cur_field_to_update.FIELD_NAME = 'SOURCE_FIELD2'
                 THEN
                    v_update_values := 
                        v_update_values
                        || ', CASE WHEN NVL('''
                        || data_cur.IND_TYPE
                        || ''', NULL) <> ''D'' THEN NULL ELSE TO_NUMBER(NVL('
                        || cur_field_to_update.FIELD_NAME
                        || ','
                        || TARGET_FIELD2
                        || ')) END';
```

Which ends up looking like..

```
UPDATE target_table 
SET (target_field1,target_field2) = 
(SELECT source_field1, 
CASE WHEN NVL('A',NULL) <> 'A' 
THEN NULL   
ELSE TO_NUMBER(NVL(source_field2,target_field2))
END 
FROM source_table);
```

Comment: your question seems not clear please post a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: i have posted a first answer let me know if this is waht you need

Comment: try this update table set target_field2 = (case when source_field2 is not null then 1 else target_field2)

Comment: When i add the update statement it is saying "an error occurred while submitting"

Comment: what is the datatype for target_field2?

Comment: Please see update

Answer (score 8):

If you need to update one field unconditionally, but only update another field if the new value is not null, you could use [`NVL()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) to choose between the new and old value:

```
update your_table set
 target_1 = source_1,
 target_2 = NVL(source_2, target_2)
where ...
```

If you update from a select statement, you can do something like this:

```
update target_table set
  (target_1, target_2) = (
    select source_1, 
           (NVL(source_2, 
               (select target_2 from target_table tt
                where tt.target_key = key_value)))
  )
where target_key = key_value;
```

This assumes that `target_key` is a unique key, so we're updating the same record.

If you have more complicated logic, dropping into PL/SQL is likely easier and less error-prone.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't have an Oracle DB around to test it; it _should_ be correct, but be warned.

Comment: Not sure if this will work as I am doing an update using a select.

Comment: Your updte statement, as shown in the post, will set every row of the table to the same values. I'm writing an update statement that works per-row now.

Comment: No, this is being iterated over a loop.

Comment: @user3224907: In any case, `update` without a `where` clause updates _every_ row.

Comment: Yes, but there is a where clause just not shown in my description. I have decided to leave it to PL/SQL which addressed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of source_field is in the same row

```
update your_table 
set target_field2 = 'your_value'
where source_field2  is not null
```

;

or if the value is the source_field itself

```
update your_table 
set target_field2 =  suorce_field2
where source_field2  is not null
```

Comment: easy to understand concept - you spelled suorce wrong though

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. I load the existing data to variables and do nvl against these existing data.

```
PROCEDURE UpdateInventoryCheck(vCondition in varchar2, vQtyOH in number,
                             vQtyAvail in number, vSN in varchar2, vLoc in varchar2,
                             vConsignment in varchar2, vNotes in varchar2,
                             vInventoryID in number) AS
cond varchar2(10);
qtyOH number;
qtyAvail number;
sn varchar2(40);
loc varchar2(15);
consig varchar2(20);
notes clob;

BEGIN

select      cond, qty_oh, qty_avail, serial_numb, loc, consignment, notes 
into        cond, qtyOH, qtyAvail, sn, loc, consig, notes
from        qctl2.inventory_check
where       inventory_id = vInventoryID;

update      qctl2.inventory_check
set         cond = nvl(vCondition, cond),
            qty_oh = nvl(vQtyOH, qtyOH),
            qty_avail = nvl(vQtyAvail, qtyAvail),
            serial_numb = nvl(vSN, sn),
            loc = nvl(vLoc, loc),
            consignment = nvl(vConsignment, consig),
            notes = nvl(vNotes, notes)
where       inventory_id = vInventoryID;
commit;

END UpdateInventoryCheck;
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE target_table 
SET target_field1 = case when target_field1 is null then null else value end
where 
conditions....